# xdebugの設定が反映されない？

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache, netbeans

お世話になります。apache,Xdebugなどの初心者です。

***＜最終的に実現したいこと＞***
NetBeansから、VM上のサーバーで動くPHPのデバッグ（ブレークポイントが止められる）をしたい。

***＜起こっている問題＞***
Server上でapacheを入れてゲストサーバー上のphpファイルにアクセスすることはできましたが、
NetBeansからブレークポイントを貼ってデバッグしようとするとブレークポイントで止まらず、実行をした際と同じような挙動になってしまいます。

***＜試したこと＞***
Xdebugをインストールし、phpinfo()が記載された＜ゲストサーバーアドレス＞/info.phpへアクセスし、Xdebugの項目群が表示されるようになることは確認できました。
また、Loaded Configuration File項目に書かれているphp.iniファイルを

```
sudo vim /etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini
```

にて一番下に以下を追記しました。

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so”
xdebug.remote_host=172.17.101.220
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

その後apacheをリスタート

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

再び
`＜ゲストサーバーアドレス＞/info.php`
へアクセス（またはF5キー押下）

⇒設定したはずの`xdebug.remote_host`や`xdebug.remote_enable`などの項目が変わらず、変更できていないように見える。この部分が原因ではないかと考えましたが、これ以降の解決策が思いつかず困っています。

なお、NetBeans上でプロジェクトのプロパティ→実行構成→デバッグURLを毎回開くを選択
も行っていますがブレークポイントで止まりません。

***＜その他気になること＞***
`locate php.ini`
にて`php.ini`ファイルを検索すると、先述した
`/etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini`（`info.php`のLoaded Configuration Fileにはこちらが書かれています）
の他に
`/etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini`
というファイルも存在しているのが少し気になります。

***＜お願い、質問＞***
上記の解決策、チェックすべき項目などお分かりになる方がいらっしゃいましたら、予想でも構いませんのでご教示いただけますと大変助かります。

***＜環境＞***
VM : Hyper-V
ホストOS : Windows10 Pro
ゲストOS : ubuntu18.04 Server
apache : apache2
NetBeans : netbeans8.2

---以下コメントを受けての追記分---
***＜PHP5.6の設定方法＞***
バージョン確認
`sudo apt show php`
→PHP7.2

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
`sudo apt update`
`sudo apt install php5.6`
`sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php5.6 libapache2-mpm-itk`

その後Xdebugを
`sudo apt-get install php-xdebug`
にてインストールし、
`sudo vim /etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini`
に上記のXdebug設定を追記しました。

しかし、このphp.iniのXdebugの内容をいくら編集しても、info.phpへ反映されません。

※最終的にはNetBeansでブレークポイントが使えれば良いので、ここが原因ではないかもしれません。

Comment: apacheのエラーログは確認していますか？

Comment: わざわざPHP5.6を使っておられますがこれはUbuntu18.04の標準リポジトリには含まれていないかと思います。なんらかのppaを利用されているかと思いますが、xdebugのインストールに至るまでの手順も記載いただけますか？設定する際に参考にされた資料などがあればそちらも。(あと、「変更できていないように見える。」ということですが追記前にもすでにxdebugの項目が表示されていたということですか？)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。apacheのログに関しては見方がまだ分かっておらず、調査中です。ありがとうございます。おっしゃる通りubuntu18.04では標準がphp7になっていたので、ppaで5.6で動作するように設定しました。手順は追記として書かせていただきました。（これも調べながら行ったもので、もしかしたらここも適切ではないかもしれません）

Comment: 色々と調べているのですが、どうも`sudo apt-get install php-xdebug`で入れたxdebugだとphp7用になっていて、そのままだとphp5は使えないのかもしれないという可能性に着目して調べていますが、まだ解決までいたっておりません。